# If $(AB)^n = 0$, must $(BA)^n=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices. If $(AB)^n = 0$, must $(BA)^n=0$? I believe it's true but don't know how to pove it. To clarify, $n$ here is not just any arbitrary integer but the dimension of the matrices.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. As stated it could be interpreted as Atmos found a counterexample for. But as another commenter mentioned, for $n=2$ they are both zero, so there **exists** such an $n$ but not **for all**.

Comment: Do you mean that for $n\times n$ matrices $A,B$ that if $(AB)^k = 0$ for some $k$, then $(BA)^k = 0$ or do you mean to reuse the dimension $n$ as the power as well? I really don't understand why such a poorly posed and no-effort-show question is being upvoted as much as it is..

Comment: Same here, upvotes on questions are pretty random in my opinion. People tend to upvote when they think the question is interesting enough, no matter the amount of effort shown in it. (I am guilty of this as well sometimes) @CameronWilliams

Comment: @CameronWilliams I think he is ruling out the trivial counterexample

Comment: The jordan block and its transpose are nice counterexamples to a lot of interpretations you may give to your question

Comment: @Exodd There is no counterexample, because $AB$ and $BA$ have the same characteristic polynomial (and therefore, if one is nilpotent, the other is).

Comment: @Gae.S. Could you elaborate a bit more? I assume you have a proof for why it is true?

Comment: The function $M_n(\Bbb C)\times M_n(\Bbb C)\to \Bbb C_{\le n}[t]$ sending $(A,B)\mapsto \det(tI-AB)-\det(tI-BA)$ can be seen as a map $\Bbb C^{n^2}\times\Bbb C^{n^2}\to\Bbb C^{n+1}$ assigning to each pair of matrices the vector of coefficients of the polynomial. Each of the entries is a polynomial in the entries of the matrices, and therefore Euclidean-continuous. The maps are $0$ on the Euclidean-dense subset $GL(n,\Bbb C)\times\Bbb C^{n^2}$ because if $A$ is invertible then $\det(tI-AB)=\det(A)\det(tI-BA)\det(A^{-1})=\det(tI-BA)$. Therefore the map is the zero map and the identity extends.